# how to foreach in inner array

Tags: php, laravel

**in my relation database,**

if id_sub_bidang = 1 then nama_sub_bidang "frontend deveoper".

if id_sub_bidang = 2 then nama_sub_bidang "senior marketing"

**my code**

```
$data = Company::find($id);

            $result_data = array();

            foreach ($data->posting_job as $hasil) {

                foreach ($data->sub_bidang as $value) {

                   $result_data[] = [

                        'id_sub_bidang' => $hasil->id_sub_bidang,
                        'nama_sub_bidang' => $value->nama
                    ]; 
                }

            }

            return response()->json($result_data);
```

**the output**

```
    [
      {
        "id_sub_bidang": 1,
        "nama_sub_bidang": "Frontend Developer"
      },
      {
        "id_sub_bidang": 1,
        "nama_sub_bidang": "Senior Marketing"
      },
      {
        "id_sub_bidang": 2,
        "nama_sub_bidang": "Frontend Developer"
      },
      {
        "id_sub_bidang": 2,
        "nama_sub_bidang": "Senior Marketing"
      }
]
```

**expected result**

```
[
      {
        "id_sub_bidang": 1,
        "nama_sub_bidang": "Frontend Developer"
      },
      {
        "id_sub_bidang": 2,
        "nama_sub_bidang": "Senior Marketing"
      }
]
```

i want to loop in inner array but doesnt work. so, i use this way. 
what the problem ?

Comment: share your `$data` ?

Comment: what's your expected result ?

Comment: @martiendt sorry, has been added :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your foreach loops to this:

```
foreach ($data->posting_job as $hasil) {

        foreach ( $hasil->id_sub_bidang as $hasilid) {

                $result_data[] = ['id_sub_bidang' => $hasil->id_sub_bidang];

                foreach ($data->sub_bidang as $value) {
                   $result_data[] = ['nama_sub_bidang' => $value->nama]; 
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

this code ** foreach ( $hasil->id_sub_bidang as $hasilid) **

Answer (score 0):

Build an array then using the method recursive to clean the array by duplicate entry.

[array_replace_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php)

---

Another solution

```
    $empty_stats = Array(
    'id_sub_bidang' => null,
    'nama_sub_bidang' => null
);

foreach ($array as $value) {
    if (!array_key_exists($id_sub_bidang, $array)) {
        $array[] = $empty_stats;
    }
    $array[] = [

        'id_sub_bidang' => $hasil->id_sub_bidang,
        'nama_sub_bidang' => $value->nama
    ]; 
}
```